# Change the cursor icon for Android Emulator in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation, qemu

I am happy to have x86 Android emulation, and I want to now use it for promotional videos of my apps.  One last thing to fix is to change the mouse cursor from a pointer to a translucent dot.

I started to look at it, and blogs point me in the direction of recompiling the Android source.  No problem.  However, even with the source, I cannot find the place where the Android emulator is drawn.  I know it uses QEMU, but I am not sure if the Window rendering is being helped by this library and maybe I should be looking at QEMU to get to the code for the cursor.

Any pointers are appreciated.